# Wildcard in Ansible inventory group

Tags: ansible

I have hosts groups defined in the single inventory file. Groups are split into datacenters.

```
[first.dc1]
...
[second.dc1]
...
[first.dc2]
...
[second.dc2]
...
```

I want to define child grouping all groups with suffix dc1

```
[dc1:children]
*.dc1
```

Is it possible in Ansible? I've tried *, all, ranges but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this seems to be not possible. Ranges in Ansible inventroy are defined as `[1:99]` but this only is expanded in hostnames, not in host group names. Also there are no wildcards.

You could help yourself with an [inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html), which dynamically generates the group dependencies.

Comment: It's strange because the documentation says, "You also don’t have to manage by strictly defined groups. Individual host names, IPs and groups, can also be referenced using wildcards", but in my experience, it is not true.

Comment: @ambe5960 I think the sentence you mention refers to `ansible` command line pattern mechanism, which does not work the same as the inventory